# Mute sound of individual app that has no sound playing

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome

There are various ways to mute or alter the volume of an application that makes sound, because once it does, it will show up in the Windows Volume Mixer.

But I'm at work right now and would like to mute my browser before I start playing audio (read: a game) in it.

My computer plays a radio continuously through the speakers, and if I mute my system audio just to hide sounds from this browser, the radio also stops which will tell others that I might play games.

Is there a way to make sure any program but in this specific case, Chrome Browser to never play any audio while other apps on the pc can?

Comment: I use [EarTrumpet](https://www.microsoft.com/pt-pt/p/eartrumpet/9nblggh516xp?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) ([GitHub page](https://github.com/File-New-Project/EarTrumpet)) all the time and you can adjust the volume for each app. It's available on the Microsoft Store. I'm not sure if it can be automated if you start a game to mute certain apps or not.

Comment: @CaldeiraG Yeah, and this does exactly the same as all the other methods I know. It won't show me the app that is running but not playing any sound, so it doesn't work. Personally I like the WIN+G option more than EarTrumpet, but both show the same audio apps, and in both cases Chrome is missing because no audio is playing.

Comment: On my computer, it shows all the apps running that played audio atleast once, so, if I fire up a youtube video and leave, Chrome will remain in EarTrumpet.